# Apply an Class by using VueJS condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I'm trying to apply a `class` to a `<p>` tag using a VueJS condition but it doesn't work at all, despite it working on JSfiddle. It's been 3 days now that I'm stuck, please help me.

VueJS (in main.js)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#test",
  data: {
    selected: "2"
  }
});
```

HTML (App.vue)

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="test">
    {{ selected }}
    <p :class="{ selection: 1 === selected }">
      heyyy 1
    </p>
    <p :class="{ selection: 2 == selected }">
      heyyy 2
    </p>
    <button @click="selected = 2">Switch</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure you are using the same code in local as in JSFiddle? one to think to note that classes wont be applied if the class names are kebab case(separated by hyphens) and you don't enclose them in quotes in VueJS. To over come you need to enclose the class name in single quotes as answered by anand vikram singh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're using Vue-CLI since you have a `.vue` file, but your `main.js` is using syntax from Vue CDN.  Maybe you copied the code from the fiddle instead.

I'll assume too that you have a CSS class named `.selection` for this to work.

Either way, `App.vue` has its own component instance which is *not* the `main.js` mounting instance (it's one level deeper).  Your code creates `selected` in the mounting root instead of `App.vue`.

To fix, create it in `App.vue` `<script>` section instead:

```html
<template>
<div id="app">
  <div id="test">
    {{ selected }}
    <p :class="{ selection: 1 === selected }">
      heyyy 1
    </p>
    <p :class="{ selection: 2 == selected }">
      heyyy 2
    </p>
    <button @click="selected = 2">Switch</button>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "2"
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.selection {
  /* CSS */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

to apply class binding in VueJs you can use it as :

`:class="{ 'selection(your class name here)': selected === 1}"`

Comment: Thank you for your help but 'selection' is actually my Class already.

Comment: see my syntax and your syntax carefully @Hamza, i am writing class name inside `''`